# EndDocPrinter Sleeps 3 secs without Shell (explorer.exe)

Tags: windows, printing, windows-xp, embedded

On Debug, when the POS has the default windows shell (explorer.exe) it prints sucessfully, but if we replace the default windows shell with our program or any other program (for example cmd.exe) and we print with the same functions, it sleeps on the EndDocPrinter call about 3 secs.

Is unnaceptable to print 3 tickets in 12 secs, and i have no idea what to test now.

An a workarround will be to start the standard shell without taskbar (blue bottom bar), but apparently it is not posible to make it hidden from start to end of the windows session.

It is not a problem of the driver, cause we test it with our printer driver and some standard printer drivers as generic text only, hplaserjet4, etc.

Developing a POS with Windows XP Embedded, Windows Embedded 2009, Windows XP Proferssional.

Printing a Documents with the OpenPrinter, StartDocPrinter, StartPagePrinter, WritePrinter, EndPagePrinter and EndDocPrinter Functions

Answer (score 0):

I disassembled EndDocPrinter, and it seems to try to find a window with classname PrintTray_Notify_WndClass. Registering a new class with that name and creating a hidden window got rid of the delay. This is an ugly workaround that can break at any time. Tested only in XP SP3.

Of course, after all that work I googled PrintTray_Notify_WndClass and found this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/embeddedwindowscomponents/thread/ecff648f-fc01-477c-ba3b-b92272c4f3a4

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.